# Need suggestion in deciding the type of the parameter(query/header) in an existing REST API

Tags: java, rest, http, device

We have a REST GET endpoint that returns device details. Something like this.

```
GET /device/{device_name}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "device_type": "ABC",
  "device_name": "XYZ",
  ...
}
```

**Requirement**

There is a requirement to send back the device status as well. We need to do that without breaking existing contract.

**My Solution**

We will take an additional optional parameter to initiate the device status check and the status will be returned in the response. This will be completely optional field so won't break the existing contract.

**My Dilemma**

Since query parameter is generally used to filter the response, I am inclined to take this parameter in the request header.

**I need your inputs in**

Suggesting whether this should be a query or header parameter.

**Thanks in advance!**

**Update**

I have decided to use query parameter, because my need resembles to sort of filtering the attributes of the resource based on optional parameter.

Something like this:

```
GET /device/{device_name}?status=true
```

Comment: Taking an optional parameter is the better option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it is asking multiple questions and both are matters of opinion and thus off-topic.

Comment: Aren't software design patterns based on opinion? Aren't many of the best practices of REST?

I know the policy here at stack overflow, but I don't get why asking for best practices from others from the industry is not allowed.

Thanks for all who replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would just return the following JSON:

```
{
  "device_type": "ABC",
  "device_name": "XYZ",
  ...
  "status": "operational"
}
```

If the clients are badly written, then this might break them. If this is a problem, then add a new endpoint:

```
GET /device/{device_name}?verbose=true
GET /device/{device_name}/status
GET /device/{device_name}/with-status
GET /device/{device_name}?with-status=true
```

Another option is versioning the API and do

```
GET api/v1/device/{device_name}
GET api/v2/device/{device_name}
```

I would not use header for this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
I am well aware of the consequences of badly written client that doesn't ignore the additional fields.
I will seek the feedback from our clients before implementing this.